# bad prediction when having noise on the data: LSTM time-series regression

Tags: long-short-term-memory, data-preprocessing, regression, training-datasets

I want to predict the force plate using a smart insole using the LSTM model for time series prediction. the data on the force plate has positive and negative values (I think the resulting positive value is a noise). if I ignore the positive value, then the predicted results of the data testing will be bad. but if I change the positive value to 0 then the prediction results will be good. what should I do if I want to keep positive value without changing it but have good prediction result.

Force Plate Shape

> 2050,1

Smart Insole Shape

> 2050,89

below are my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import math
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,RepeatVector, LSTM, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten, Conv1D, MaxPooling1D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Bidirectional, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
%matplotlib inline

## Load Data
Insole = pd.read_csv('1113_Rwalk40s1_list.txt', header=None, low_memory=False)
SIData =  np.asarray(Insole)

df = pd.read_csv('1113_Rwalk40s1.csv', low_memory=False)
columns = ['Fx']
selected_df = df[columns]
FCDatas = selected_df[:2050]
## End Load Data

## Concatenate Data
SmartInsole = np.array(SIData[:2050])
FCData = np.array(FCDatas)
# FCData = np.where(FCData>0, 0, FCData) #making positive value to 0
Dataset = np.concatenate((SmartInsole, FCData), axis=1)
## End Concatenate Data


## Normalization Data
scaler_in = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaler_out = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
data_scaled_in = scaler_in.fit_transform(Dataset[:,0:89])
data_scaled_out = scaler_out.fit_transform(Dataset[:,89:90])
## End Normalization Data

steps= 50
inp = []
out = []
for i in range(len(data_scaled_out) - (steps)):
    inp.append(data_scaled_in[i:i+steps])
    out.append(data_scaled_out[i+steps])

inp= np.asanyarray(inp)
out= np.asanyarray(out)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(inp, out, test_size=0.25,random_state=2)

## Model Building
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, activation='relu',  return_sequences= False, input_shape= (50,89)))
model.add(Dense(32,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.002), metrics=['mse'])
model.summary()
## End Model Building

## Model fit
history = model.fit(x_train,y_train, epochs=50, verbose=2, batch_size=64, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
## End Model fit

## Model Loss Plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='Train Loss')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='Test Loss')
plt.title('model loss')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epochs')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
## End Model Loss Plot

## Prediction and Model Evaluation
model.evaluate(inp, out)
predictions=model.predict(inp)

print('MSE: ',mean_squared_error(out, predictions))
print('RMSE: ',math.sqrt(mean_squared_error(out, predictions)))
print('Coefficient of determination (r2 Score): ', r2_score(out, predictions))

#invert normalize
predictions = scaler_out.inverse_transform(predictions) 
out = scaler_out.inverse_transform(out) 

x=[]
colors=['red','green','brown','teal','gray','black','maroon','orange','purple']
colors2=['green','red','orange','black','maroon','teal','blue','gray','brown']
x = np.arange(0,2000)*40/2000 
for i in range(0,1):
    plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))
    plt.plot(x,out[0:2000,i],color=colors[i])
    plt.plot(x,predictions[0:2000,i],markerfacecolor='none',color=colors2[i])
    plt.title('LSTM Regression (Training Data)')
    plt.ylabel('Force/Fx (N)')
    plt.xlabel('Time(s)')
    plt.legend(['Real value', 'Predicted Value'], loc='lower left')
    plt.savefig('Regression Result.png'[i])
    plt.show()

## End Prediction and Model Evaluation

## Model Validation
Test_Insole = pd.read_csv('1113_Rwalk40s2_list.txt', header=None, low_memory=False)
TestSIData =  np.asarray(Test_Insole)

Test_df = pd.read_csv('1113_Rwalk40s2.csv', low_memory=False)
Test_columns = ['Fx']
Test_selected_df = Test_df[Test_columns]
Test_FCDatas = Test_selected_df[:2050]

test_SmartInsole = np.array(TestSIData[:2050]) 
test_FCData = np.array(Test_FCDatas)
# test_FCData = np.where(test_FCData>0, 0, test_FCData) #making positive value to 0
test_Dataset = np.concatenate((test_SmartInsole, test_FCData), axis=1)

test_scaler_in = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
test_scaler_out = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
test_data_scaled_in = test_scaler_in.fit_transform(test_Dataset[:,0:89])
test_data_scaled_out = test_scaler_out.fit_transform(test_Dataset[:,89:90])

test_steps= 50
test_inp = []
test_out = []
for i in range(len(test_data_scaled_out) - (test_steps)):
    test_inp.append(test_data_scaled_in[i:i+test_steps])
    test_out.append(test_data_scaled_out[i+test_steps])

test_inp= np.asanyarray(test_inp)
test_out= np.asanyarray(test_out)

model.evaluate(test_inp, test_out)
test_predictions=model.predict(test_inp)

test_predictions = test_scaler_out.inverse_transform(test_predictions) 
test_out = test_scaler_out.inverse_transform(test_out) 

x=[]
colors=['red','green','brown','teal','gray','black','maroon','orange','purple']
colors2=['green','red','orange','black','maroon','teal','blue','gray','brown']
x = np.arange(0,2000)*40/2000 
for i in range(0,1):
    plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))
    plt.plot(x,test_out[0:2000,i],color=colors[i])
    plt.plot(x,test_predictions[0:2000,i],markerfacecolor='none',color=colors2[i])
    plt.title('LSTM Regression (Testing Data)')
    plt.ylabel('Force/Fx (N)')
    plt.xlabel('Time(s)')
    plt.legend(['Real value', 'Predicted Value'], loc='lower left')
    plt.savefig('Regression Result.png'[i])
    plt.show()

## End Model validation
```

the Result without changing the positive value
[image]

the Result if I changing the positive value to 0
[image]